# C - How to generate random numbers between 20 and 30?

Tags: c, random

I've tried but it doesn't seem to give me the desired numbers. Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int n, i;
   printf("Value of n:\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   int t[n];
   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%d ", rand()%20+30);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is most definitely a duplicate question — one that has been asked and answered many times before.  The range may vary, but values between 10 and 20 is not very different from between 20 and 30.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I found a more elaborate dupe, with a step, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `rand()%10+20`.

`rand()%10` gives numbers between `0` and `9`. Adding then `20` will give numbers between `20`and `29`.

For numbers between `20` and `30` (inclusive), use `rand()%11+20`.

Comment: Apart from the off-by-one bug...

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("%d ", rand()%20+30);
```

generates random numbers between 30 and 50 (not included). You need

```
printf("%d ", rand()%10+20);
```

to generate between 20 and 30 (not included)

`10` being the range, and `20` being the offset.

To include both end points (giving 11 possible values):

```
printf("%d ", rand()%11+20);
```

Comment: I'm going to argue that there's an off-by-one bug here too; the range quoted normally includes both end points in plain English, so it should be `rand() % (max - min + 1) + min`.  That ignores subtleties like the slight bias when `(max - min + 1)` does not exactly divide RAND_MAX.

Comment: edited to enclude both end points (that was clear enough in my previous answer). You're right about the bias. I wouldn't vouch about the uniform properties of that code.

Answer (score 1):

these are the expressions

`number = 21 + rand() % 9 // for (20, 30)`

`number = 20 + rand() % 11 // for [20, 30]`

Comment: Apart from the off-by-one bug...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is ok now I think!

Comment: Given the edit to `number = 21 + rand() % 9`, the result looks like a number in the range 21..29 now.  The start point was OK; it was the modulus that was giving trouble.  Assuming max > min, then `rand() % (max - min + 1) + min` is normal.

Comment: the question says to generate numbers between 20 & 30, so I think they should not be included.

Comment: I'll repeat a comment I made to someone else:— 
 
Weird. If someone says "give me a number in the range 1 to 6" for simulating a six-sided dice, the end values are both included. Normal speech includes the end points. If you're going to use the asymmetric range (or the exclusive range), say so.  But common speech includes the end points.

Comment: Eddited my answer!!   I agree to your point, but there is difference in saying 'a number in range 20-30' and 'a number between 20-30'.

Answer (score 0):

To generate random number in range [A .. B], first take difference between numbers: D = B-A, then generate a random number in the range of [0..D] and add that to A:

```
unsigned myRand(unsigned fromA, unsigned toB)
{
    if (fromA > toB)  // check if fromA is 
        return myRand(toB, fromA);
    int d = toB - fromA; // difference between numbers: D = B-A  
    int r = rand() % (d+1); // random number in the range of [0..D]
    return r + fromA;
}
```

Or, you may just to it manually like this:

```
20 + (rand()%11)
```

Also, note that depending on implementation [rand()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) returns values between 0 and RAND_MAX, so you won't be able to create random values large than RAND_MAX (which might be as small as 32767). In this cases you may combine multiple `rand()` calls to get large random numbers:

```
unsigned r = (rand() << 16) | rand();
```

Comment: Apart from the off-by-one bug...

Comment: I assume range of [A..B)

Comment: Weird.  If someone says "give me a number in the range 1 to 6" for simulating a six-sided dice, the end values are _both_ included.  Normal speech includes the end points.  If you're going to use the asymmetric range, say so.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler agree, code updated.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` may be as small as 32767 (0x7FFF).  The conversion of `unsigned/int/unsigned` is a problem for large values, yet for those, one needs a different approach.

Comment: When `RAND_MAX` is as small as 32767, often `int` is 16 bit and `rand() << 16` is `int` overflow (UB)  (I think you wanted `<< 15` here anyways).  Perhaps something closer to `unsigned r = rand()*(RAND_MAX + 1u) ^ rand();`